# Как написать в Java выражение ln^2(a*x+2)

Tags: java

Как написать в Джаве выражение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Непонятно как в Джаве написать вторую степень между `ln` и `(ax+2)`

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: что именно вызывает сложности?

Comment: Непонятно как в Джаве написать вторую степень между ln и (ax+2)

Comment: непонятно, почему вы решили, что вторую степень нужно писать между именно ln и (ax+2). Что в этой формуле возводится в квадрат?

Comment: Я не знаю. Я смотрел формулы логарифмов, не нашёл там такого, чтобы сначала был логарифм, потом степень, потом число...

Comment: вы не смотрите формулы, а просто подумайте. Аналогия: sin²(0.5). Что здесь во второй степени?

Comment: Я не знаю. Если бы знал, то не спрашивал бы

Comment: в java  есть прекрасный класс-Math. Данный класс имеет набор статических методов удовлятворяющих вашему вкусу: Math.pow(),  Math.log() и много других полезных методов. Если класс Мath вам по каким то причина не нравится, то могу порекомендовать OpenBLAS, замечательная билиотека,  правда сторонняя,  но бесплатная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В математике запись [image: формула1] означает возведение в квадрат результата от взятия логарифама. Эту же запись можно написать так: [image: формула2].

В Java натуральный логарифм можно вычислить с помощью [`Math.log()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-), а возвести число во вторую степень — с помощью [`Math.pow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-):

```java
double a = ...;
double x = ...;
double result = Math.pow(Math.log(a * x + 2), 2);
```

Comment: предвижу вопрос - почему в формуле степень между `ln` и `ax+2`, а у тебя в конце :)